# Need to start Alarm when screen is off?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to start repeating Alarm when screen is off, but Alarm is not starting when screen is off, How can I start this Alarm?

Code to start Alarm :

```
    Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(context, receiverClass);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            requestCode, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + (minutes * 60 * 1000),
            (minutes * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you should use a service and use notification to raise an alarm. When the app is not a foreground app, you should use service which can still run in the background and set an alarm by notification. Just like
NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);